# Javascript - refresh value of parameter on call of internal function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Considering this part of a code, i need to know how to, on button click, the text of textbox be written on console.

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="ttb_text" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function AppendButton() {
    var _text = '';
    if (!!arguments[0]) {
      _text = (arguments[0]['text'] || 'nothing to log');
    }

    $('body').append('<input type="button" id="btn_button" value="Log Text" />');

    $('body').on('click', '#btn_button', function () {
      console.log(_text);
    });
  }

  AppendButton({
    text: $('#ttb_text').val()
  });

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your logic why are you doing this but what do you want can be achieved by getting `#ttb_text` value inside onclick callback.

```
<body>
   <input type="text" id="ttb_text" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
      function AppendButton() {
          var _text = '';
          if (!!arguments[0]) {
             _text = (arguments[0]['text'] || 'nothing to log');
          }

          $('body').append('<input type="button" id="btn_button" value="Log Text" />');

      $('body').on('click', '#btn_button', function () {
         _text = $('#ttb_text').val();
         console.log(_text);
      });
     }

 AppendButton({
    text: $('#ttb_text').val()
 });

 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a simplified example of a function that adds some components into DOM, i did by this way to be easely understood, by the way, it not worked :). What i need is that on click, the function must update the the _text parameter with the current value of the #ttb_text.